# Is there a way to enable a JQuery popup for IE8 users and below?

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser, popup

I have a new site built with CSS3, but have used some conditional style sheets to make it look reasonable in IE8 and below.

However I would like to place a popup on the site for all visitors using IE8 or lower. This will simply inform them that the site will be usable, but in order to enjoy the full enhancements they should update their browser. I will then provide 2 links in the popup, one to download Firefox and the other to continue without updating.

I would like to do this with JQuery.

I need a method I could use to target other browsers as well, e.g. Firefox so I can test it works. I am a Mac user and have limited access to IE for testing. So a solution I can test on other browsers and then switch the code to target IE8 and below would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) to detect if the features you are using are not supported. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/4SHUq/1/):

```
if(!Modernizr.flexbox) {
  alert("Flexbox not supported");
}
```